# twoSum II - Leet Code - run time error - out of bound

Tags: java

problem : twoSum II
Given an array of integers numbers that is already sorted in non-decreasing order, find two numbers such that they add up to a specific target number.

Return the indices of the two numbers (1-indexed) as an integer array answer of size 2, where 1 <= answer[0] < answer[1] <= numbers.length.

The tests are generated such that there is exactly one solution. You may not use the same element twice.

```
Input: numbers = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [1,2]

Explanation: The sum of 2 and 7 is 9. Therefore index1 = 1, index2 = 2.
```

```
    
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        
        int a_pointer = 0;
        int b_pointer = numbers.length - 1;
        
        while (a_pointer < b_pointer) {
            int sum=numbers[a_pointer] + numbers[b_pointer];
            
            if (sum > target) {
                 b_pointer-=1;
            } else if (sum < target) {
                b_pointer+=1;
            } else {
                return new int[] {a_pointer+1, b_pointer+1};
            }           
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no match found");
    }
};
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
  at line 8, Solution.twoSum
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 87, __Driver__.main
```

when run test case

```
[5,25,75]
100
```

Comment: Since you know the input that breaks your code, you can debug the problem. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips on how to do that.

Comment: else if (sum < target) {
                b_pointer+=1;
            } 

You need to do a_pointer++ here

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're increasing the value of b_pointer in one your condition, due to which it becomes the size of array (as you're intialising it as arr.length - 1)

```
 else if (sum < target) {
                b_pointer+=1;
            }
```